# Lost rep from removed posts does not show in the achievement list

Tags: support, bug, reputation, achievements-dialog

I noticed I had lost some rep over on Stack Overflow, but nothing shows up in the achievement bar (related to that):

[image]

But when looking in the reputation tab on my profile:

[image]

There's -15 rep from a removed post (most likely an answer).

Why is it that this doesn't show up in the achievements list?

<sub>If relevant, the post was not self-removed</sub>

Comment: Well, I'd say this is by design, since anyone who is trying to constructively help SE wont consider rep loss as an "achievement".

Comment: @Unitato thing is, it does show rep loss for other events.

Comment: As Sha said: other forms of negative rep show up there (like downvotes, whether given or received, when applicable accepted edits denied by the owner). This should too

Comment: This also happens when a user is removed if that user had upvoted on any questions or answers you've posted.. If your browser keeps a history of URL's, you may be able to go back to that post to find out who deleted it.

Comment: You could also ask a Moderator in your group who should be able to see that information.